# Searching, Sorting and Graph Algorithms questions

Tags: algorithm, search, sorting, graph, computer-science

Is there a resource that i can find different variations of searching, sorting and graph algorithm questions ?

I have studied CLRS and Algorithm Design by Kleinberg. and solved some set of questions.

I have also, checked SO for algorithms questions.

Curious, if there is a resource you would highly recommend.

**EDIT:** There is also this free [ebook](http://www.eng.unt.edu/ian/books/free/poa.pdf) with many questions, that i was able to solve some of them.

**EDIT:** Also, not interested in competition questions such as TopCoder and algorithmist, etc.

Kind of questions i like:

given an array of numbers from 1 to n, there many m 1's in this array, and the rest is zero, describe an efficient algorithm to find where your 1's end and 0's begin. What s the time complexity.

Like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/) has a link to [problemsets](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/List_of_Problemsets) that you can dig into.  The Online Judges require implementation to check your answer, but there's no reason why you can't read the problems and try to figure it out without implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for some sites with ACM contests' problems, like http://uva.onlinejudge.org/.

Most of these sites has forums (like http://online-judge.uva.es/board/). So you can read some complex problems (most problems with low accept rate are complex) and then read related threads on forums.